# How to send the reviews on my fb page from my site to my fb page?

Tags: angular, facebook, npm, mean-stack, fbsdk

I have a website in which I show my company Facebook page, I mean I will integrate my Facebook page on my website.If a user comes and provides a review on my website the same need to be updated on my Facebook page too.Is there any chance of implementing this functionality in angular 2?Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/#Creating

> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

There is no way to post ratings/reviews on Facebook Pages with the API.